# Change the default schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a quick question. So, I logged to the sql server via 
    `sqlcmd -s localhost -u testuser -d my_db` .

After I tried to change the default schema of my_db

`ALTER USER testuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=testdb` and got issue 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression'

Anybody can help me with changing the default schema?

Comment: [Your syntax seems valid to me...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

Comment: I can't replicate the issue either. I feel like we're missing something here. (*No fiddle supplied as DB<>Fiddle doesn't allow the creation of Users, and SQL Fiddle is down (again).*)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did the same, as you see.

Comment: @Larnu that is all, what I did